# How cloud Two generic parameters, one for specification and one for type inference

Tags: c#

#### Success with object return Type

```
public static class MiniSQLHelper{
    public static object SqlQuerySingleOrDefault<TParam>(this IDbConnection cnn, string query, TParam param)
        where TParam : class 
    {
        //......
    }    
}

using (var conn = Connection){
    var result = conn.SqlQuerySingleOrDefault("select @v ", new { v = 1 }); /*Success*/
}
```

#### Error with generic class return Type

```
public static class MiniSQLHelper{
    public static T SqlQuerySingleOrDefault<T, TParam>(this IDbConnection cnn, string query, TParam param)
        where TParam : class 
    {
        //......
    }    
}

using (var conn = Connection){
    var result = conn.SqlQuerySingleOrDefault<int>("select @v ", new { v = 1 });/*CS1503 C# Argument 3: cannot convert from to 'int'*/
}
```

#### Question

How cloud i do it Two generic parameters, one for specification and one for type inference.

---

#### [Online Test Demo| .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FE3SpI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `TParam` as class, but the following change removes the compilation error:

```
var result2 = MiniSQLHelper.SqlQuerySingleOrDefault<int, object>("select @v ", new { v = 1 });
```

Comment: I have to use TParam  generic parameter for another method. and i hope simplify user actions like dapper QuerySingleOrDefault<int>

Comment: I reckon you're going to use `Reflection` to get parameter class fields/properties to pass them to your SQL request, but why not using `params object[] args`? Is the only reason to have name match, rather than position match?

Comment: thanks again @Max , becauce Reflection is slow , i hope use expression complier 
 so need TParam

Comment: It looks like no solution  , thanks @Max , i click accept